# updating Multiple lines in the same time with Python

Tags: python

```
with open('G1.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('G1.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if i==10:
               f.write ("in1  G  OP  RE 1* " + str(g)+ "3500  /"+ '\n')
               f.write ("in2  G  OP  RE 1* " + str(g)+ "3500  /"+ '\n')
        elif i==20:
            f.write(str(t)+ "*31 /"+'\n')
```

I have multiple line update inside a big file, and some of those lines are multiple lines 
Every time I run the code, it removes the first line only and add the new lines to it. The output looks like this

```
in1  W  OP  RE 1*  19000  3500  /
in2  W  OP  RE 1*  19000  3500  /
in2  W  OP  RE 1*  10000  3500  /
10*31
```

In this example, you will see there is 2 in2 in the file. So, every time i run the code those lines will add up to each other. so instead of having 2 lines I might end up with extra 5 lines

```
Is there a way to remove the old second line and update it with the new one without repeating `elif i==` for every single line
Because sometime I have to update 7 or ten new lines in the same section and for different sections
```

Best Regards

Comment: For starters, if you have a **big** file do not load it whole in memory with `readlines()` just so you can loop through it. Second, it's not clear from your question what's the actual issue.

Comment: "and some of those lines are multiple lines"  could you explain what this means?

Comment: Write a generic loop that gets passed the indexes and the new content in a list?

Comment: if you look, you will see there is 2 in2 in the file. So, every time i run the code those lines will add up to each other. so instead of having 2 lines I might end up with extra 5 lines

Comment: What are `g`, `t`, and `w`? Why are you looping over the lines but then doing nothing with the `line` data?

Comment: They are just variables. And I am focusing on one proble, which updating the lines

Comment: You are not updating the lines - you keep writing new lines but you never take into the account the lines you've read.

Comment: It's good to focus on one problem, but code you post to SO should be a [mcve]. We'd like to help you, but we're having a hard time understanding exactly what you want your program to do. It might help if you posted a larger sample of the input file (say 10 to 20 lines) along with the output file that corresponds to that input.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues with the code you have posted, but do you mean this:

```
with open('G1.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('G1.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if i == 10:
            f.write( ...
            f.write( ...
        elif i == 11:
            pass
        # etc etc


        else:
            f.write(line)
```

When the code reaches line 10 it writes the two lines you want, plus when it reaches the old line 11 it doesn't write out the old line.

(Plus all lines not mentioned by line number are written back to the file)

**Update:**

```
with open('G1.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('G1.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if i == 2:
            f.write('New line 3\n')
            f.write('New line 4\n')
        elif i == 3:
            pass
        # etc etc


        else:
            f.write(line)
```

The above code (tested with Thonny and Py3.6) transforms original file:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
```

Into new file:

```
line 1
line 2
New line 3
New line 4
line 5
line 6
```

And repeated runs always leaves the file in the second state

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesnt delete the second line, it adds up to it

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The code in my answer will replace line 10 with two lines and line 11 with no lines.

Comment: in1  W  OP  RE 1*  19000  3500  /
in2  W  OP  RE 1*  19000  3500  /
in2  W  OP  RE 1*  10000  3500  /
 I am getting the same error as I was getting before

Comment: It doesnt remove the second line

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but have you considered updating the other 6 lines in the same time. Repeating pass 6 times, is not efficient. There must be a way to update them all in the same time without using elif + pass 6 times

Comment: Perhaps its time for a new question.

Comment: Actually, it is the same question but thank you very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160795/discussion-between-quamrana-and-zena).